# Retrieving User Email from FaceBook in iOS applications

Tags: iphone, email, facebook-graph-api, fbconnect

I am developing an iPhone app that requires retrieval of logged in user's email id from FaceBook through any one of FaceBook API's such as FBConnect or FBGraph for iOS.

By using FBConnect or FBGraph I could retrieve the user informations like name, id, sex etc, but I cannot retrieve user email id.

If I queried for email id, it returns 'null' for the email.

Please anyone help me out in this.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First

```
  [facebook requestWithGraphPath: @"me" andDelegate: self]
```

With @"offline access" and @"email" will give you an email address. Make sure ur email selected visible in your facebook

```
if (![objDelegate.facebook isSessionValid])
    {

    //[appDelegate.mFacebookObj authorize:App_ID permissions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:kFBPermission, nil] delegate:self];
    [objDelegate.facebook authorize:App_ID permissions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"offline_access",@"publish_stream",@"email",@"user_birthday",@"user_events",@"read_stream",@"friends_likes", nil] delegate:self];
}
```

Or you can use that [Link](http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/iphone/iphone-fbconnect-facebook-connect-tutorial/)